# Access to path of XML file is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, webforms

So I'm currently working on an ASP.NET project. It requires me to write a List<> onto a XML file. I created a "data.xml" file within the project folder and here are my few lines of code:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<BookItem>));
TextWriter filestream = new StreamWriter("data.xml");
serializer.Serialize(filestream, book);
filestream.Close();
```

Everything runs smoothly until the "write-data-to-xml-file" part. I encountered this issue:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\data.xml' is denied.'
```

Am I missing any setting or should I include any tricky line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a specific file location such as c:\data.xml as I think the reason is because it can’t write to a default location.

```
TextWriter filestream = new StreamWriter(@"c:\data.xml");
```

Comment: Can't believe it worked! But i have 1 small question. I assume the xml file is in my root project folder. If i use my full path (in this case it is "C:\...\source\WebSites\WebSite1\data.xml") then error will occur if someone open this in their machine right?

Comment: Glad it helped. Well as it’s an asp.net app, you will deploy to a server and the file will be stored somewhere on that server. The app will access the file at the location you have specificed which could be anywhere your app has permissions to really. Think of it as the app accessing the file rather than the user, and the app delivering the file to the user. StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/data.xml") is an approach

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have trouble overwriting the .xml. Is it open somewhere, e.g. your IDE? If not, do you have permission to overwrite it? Try deleting it and see if your code executes.

Comment: I believe I have the full permission on the XML file, the issue occur at this line:
TextWriter filestream = new StreamWriter("data.xml");

Comment: Because the system prevents authorization to write into the file if the file is in use or if the application trying to write into the file lacks permission to do so. The error is being called at this line of code, because this is where the writing attempt happens.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do two things

1- go to your file and change security permission and allow full control, modify, read, and write.

2- go to task manager and end `data.xml`.

Change this line

```
TextWriter filestream = new StreamWriter("data.xml");
```

into this

```
 TextWriter filestream = new StreamWriter(@"fullpath");
```

Comment: Hi there. The permission is "Full control & everything else" for all of the users in my machine and there is no "data.xml" process in the task manager

Comment: try to replace this line `TextWriter filestream = new StreamWriter("data.xml");` by this line `TextWriter filestream = new StreamWriter(@"fullpath");`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, some small problems

```
new StreamWriter("data.xml");
```

you have not specified full path and IIS try to create in relative path that is run and your IIS user has not sufficient privileges to create this file or modify existing file with the same name.
you can

```
Server.Map("~")
```

to get your running website path and create a custom path for creating your files